# Using jQuery to continually fadeOut and fadeIn Images

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/*Function that changes image periodically*/
var Images = new Array("image_four", "image_three", "image_two", "image_one");
var x = 0
setInterval(function() {
    var Id = "#" + Images[x]
    $(Id).fadeOut(1000);
    if (x==3) {
        x = 0
    }
    x++
}, 9000)
/*End of Image Changer*/
/*Coordinates of tabs*/
/*End of Coordinate*/
});
```

I want to continually change the content of a div tag, and what i was to create a div tag and place 4 images on each other and after some seconds the setInterval function fades out the image currently un top till it gets to the last i want it to get their then set x = 0 and it would create something like an infinte loop. but the code stops their please whats going on?

Comment: Well , for start,  if (x==3) { x = 0 } x++  will always give you x = 1 ,when x == 3

Comment: second, it's not like the code stops , but i think your images are faded out, and you do no reset them , so they are changing , but you just don't see it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pzmev/ Check this out

Comment: Okay yeah. Thanks they are all faded out. I need to just fade them back In.

Answer (score 0):

Not really images, but here : http://jsfiddle.net/Pzmev/1/ 
make a `$('div').fadeIn();` when you reset the counter